# Use XDebug with two separate codebases on one server

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have MAMP setup to serve two separate codebases. One is the "main" codebase that makes REST requests to the other.

I have attempted to get XDebug working for both, however it appears that I can only get one or the other working with breakpoints. When trying to do the other, I get invalid codepath errors. Is it possible to get XDebug working on two separate codebases on the same server and I'm just configuring it wrong?

The IDE I use is PhpStorm.

Comment: Check your path mappings in Preferences\Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers. Try to set them manually according to the remote server file locations.